# <ui:repeat> in JSF 2.0 breaks methods execution order

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have very simple JSF 2.0 application (see below). The problem is that when `ui:repeat` is present, execution order (I check it using breakpoints in debugger) is strange.

After I submit form, `SecondBean.initSomething()` is called before `FirstBean.setFirstFormField()`. If I change type of `something` to `String` and delete `ui:repeat` from `index.jsf` and use just `h:outputText` then everything works as expected, `FirstBean.setFirstFormField()` is called before `SecondBean.initSomething()`.

What I'm doing wrong?

I'm using JDeveloper Studio Edition 11.1.2.2.0 and its stack (WebLogic 10.3.5.0, Java 6 and JSF 2.0).

Here's the code:

index.jsf:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <h:head></h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <h:inputText value="#{firstBean.firstFormField}" />
                    <h:commandButton action="#{firstBean.processForm}" value="Submit" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
            <ui:repeat value="#{secondBean.something}" var="variable" >
                <h:outputText value="#{variable}" />
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

FirstBean.java:

```
package test.backing;

import javax.faces.bean.*;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class FirstBean {
    private String firstFormField;
    public FirstBean() {
        super();
    }

    public String processForm() {
        FacesContext facesContext;

        facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        return facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId();            
    }

    public void setFirstFormField(String firstFormField) {
        this.firstFormField = firstFormField;
    }

    public String getFirstFormField() {
        return this.firstFormField;
    }
}
```

SecondBean.java:

```
package test.backing;

import java.util.*;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import javax.faces.bean.*;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SecondBean {
    private List<String> something;

    public SecondBean() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initSomething() {
        this.something = Arrays.asList("abc", "cde");
    }

    public void setSomething(List<String> something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    public List<String> getSomething() {
        return this.something;
    }
}
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

</faces-config>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
    <param-value>*.jsf;*.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: My guess would be that `ui:repeat`, being part of Facelets (and I'm guessing not a "real" JSF component), is evaluated in an earlier phase of processing than an `h:inputText` or `h:outputText`. (Restore View versus Apply Request Values or Update Model Values.) It's been a while since I touched JSF though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What I'm doing wrong?*

Nothing. It's working as specified. It's just invoked during restoring the view.

If this is causing a specific problem for you, which is unfortunately not described in detail in the question at all, then a solution needs to be sought in a different direction than depending/relying on some specific execution order of bean construction or getter calls relative to the view. At least, that is what you seem to be targeting at for some reason.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, in that `processForm()` action method you can also just return `null` to navigate back to the current view. That's much simpler than the current clumsy approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the JSF cycle works. The order is correct...

You need to change the manner you are doing agreeing with the rules of the JSF framework.
Learn the phases of the JSF cycle, may this can help you.

Comment: Note that OP's particular problem is **unrelated** to your own problem as asked in your currently last question. Downvoting technically valid answers just because you find it "offensive" makes also no utter sense. Perhaps you should accept the fact that you simply don't understand how basic HTTP works in its core and how JSF is abstracting it (too much) away?

Answer (score 0):

You can use h:dataTable it does not populate the values during restore phase, it populates the after the updateModel pahse